# extjs: publish subscribe type facility ? want to update a content area which needs to be sync in with a dataStore

Tags: extjs, datastore, javascript-databinding

in ExtJS5, How can i update/auto-sync a text panel say c , which lists out records from a dataStore D, when D is modified dynamically through a grid G which does drag n drop actions thus updating its store ?

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs a component that is bound to a store automatically updates when the store changes. There is no need to implement that.

If you have two grid panels bound to the same store, the second will automatically show the changes you make in the first.

In your case, the second panel is a text panel. Since text panels do not contain data, but only text, you have to modify them by listening to events on the store.

ExtJs has a powerful event system in a MVC or since ExtJs 5 also a MVVM pattern.